# How to write 3D Isometric text using Sketch app?

Tags: text, sketch-app, transform, isometric

I need to write [Isometric text](https://www.midwinter-dg.com/blog_demos/css-isometric-text/) in Sketch app.

I tried using "Convert to Outlines" option to do transformation. But that doesn't help to transform the text to isometric projection.

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin for [generating isometric views](https://github.com/sureskumar/sketch-isometric) in sketch but as far as I understand it only does it in the horizontal plane.

Sketch does not have very robust transformation functions and it'd be too hard to do the isometric effect by the manual method of scaling/rotating/shearing, so  I think your best bet is to import an isometric grid (google should help you find one in ai/eps/svg format) into sketch and use that to hand draw /adjust your text. Or use another vector app, such as affinity, illustrator, or inkscape.

Comment: You can do robust transformations even manually if you have reference lines available.

Comment: exactly, that's why I suggested importing a grid. but without it, it'd be hard to do accurate (numeric) shear or scale.

Comment: Scale is no problem just type *-.7 for example in the size of the object. THe downside is that you dot have numeric input to skew. YOu need to use a line as a guide for the skew

Answer (score 1):

Convert the text to a shape.

Right click on the text you want to skew and at the bottom of the menu there should be an option that says "Convert to Outlines". You can also find this option as "Convert to Outlines" under the *Layer* menu or by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

From there you can manipulate it exactly as if it were shapes you drew. The downside is you won't be able to change the text or font, so make sure you have a copy of the layer in case you need to go back.

Answer (score 0):

There's no extrude like option in Sketch.
As Luciano states you can Convert your text to outlines and manipulate it from there.
Right click > 'Transform' gives you the option to skew the form.
To make it look like 3D I'll give you this tip:

- Duplicate the letters, place the front on at where the front of the 3D letter should be and the back one where the back of the 3D letter should be.
- Lock the front layer.
- With the pen tool change the point of the back letters so it looks like it is extruded (connect them towards the front letters)